# How to find the task which core dumped?

Tags: gdb, vxworks

Given a core dump of say a router/switch say running vxworks. How to find the task which core dumped ?

My guess list down the tasks and see which is in running state, is that right ? Please let me know .

Answer (score 1):

You can use coreDumpShow() from coreDumpLib.h (vxWorks 6.9).

```
-> coreDumpShow 0,1
NAME        IDX VALID   ERRNO      SIZE     CKSUM    TYPE        TASK
----------- --- ----- ---------- ---------- ----- ------------ ----------
vxcore1.z     1 Y            N/A 0x000ef05b OK    KERNEL_TASK  t1

Core Dump detailed information:
-------------------------------
Time:                   THU JAN 01 00:01:42 1970 (ticks = 6174)
Task:                   "t1" (0x611e0a20)
Process:                "(Kernel)" (0x6017a500)
Description:            fatal kernel task-level exception!
Exception number:       0xb
Program counter:        0x6003823e
Stack pointer:          0x604d3da8
Frame pointer:          0x604d3fb0

value = 0 = 0x0
```

You might also want to try looking in coreDumpUtilLib:

```
coreDumpIsAvailable( ) - is a kernel core dump available for retrieval 
coreDumpNextGet( ) - get the next kernel core dump on device
coreDumpInfoGet( ) - get information on a kernel core dump
coreDumpOpen( ) - open an existing kernel core dump for retrieval
coreDumpClose( ) - close a kernel core dump
coreDumpRead( ) - read from a kernel core dump file
coreDumpCopy( ) - copy a kernel core dump to the given path
```